# modifying text to a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to modify my scripts.

```
create table T1
a,
b)
/
INSERT...
/
UPDATE ...   
/
create table T2
a,
b)
/
```

I want to modify the file like:

```
create table T1
a,
b) TABLESPACE TS
/
INSERT...
/
UPDATE ...   
/
create table T2
a,
b) TABLESPACE TS
/
```

So i want to get text between "create table" and "/" and add that word "TABLESPACE TS" above the word "/".
can someone help me what options I can use here sed command?

Comment: Added `bash` tag. If you're not using bash feel free to rollback to the previous version

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
create table T1
a,
b)
/
create table T2
a,
b)
/
Some Stuff
b)
/
b) again
```

**Script**

```
sed '/^create table/{:l1;n;/^\/$/!{s/^b)$/b) TABLESPACE TS/g;b l1}}' file
```

**Output**

```
create table T1
a,
b) TABLESPACE TS
/
create table T2
a,
b) TABLESPACE TS
/
Some Stuff
b)
/
b) again
```

---

**What is happening here?**

- We used `sed` stream editor here.
- `s` option for `sed` it meant for substitution.
- `s` format is `s/pattern/replacement/g` where `g` flag serves global substitution.
- `:l1` is used to specify a label `l1`
- `n` adds next line to the pattern space after printing current space.
- `!{group}` is used to negate a  group of commands. In our case it's saying if pattern `/` is matched don't attempt `{group}` of commands.
- `b` is for *unconditional* jumping to a label. So `b l1` jumps to label `l1`.
- Now read the answer in the light of these points.

---

**Note**

`SEd` itself expanded to stream editor. For more info check [[ this ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).

Comment: There are other text as well with the word "/" so that replacement wont work.have to grab the chunk between "create table" and "/" and then need to modify.Other text need to remain same.

Comment: @AjaySingh : I see . that requirement was not mentioned initially. I will update in a moment.

Comment: @AjaySingh : I have updated to fit the requirement now.

Comment: Saved  a lot of time for me. Thanks for quick answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `/` as the record separator.

```
awk -v RS=/ -v ORS=/ -v IGNORECASE=1 '
    /create table/ { print $0, "TABLESPACE TS\n";next } 
    $0 != "\n" 
    END {printf("\n")}'  inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

with GAWK

```
    awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n/"} {printf "%s",$0} /create/{printf "%s"," TABLESPACE TS"} {printf "%s",RS}' file
```

Output

```
create table T1
a,
b) TABLESPACE TS
/
INSERT...
/
UPDATE ...
/
create table T2
a,
b) TABLESPACE TS
/
```

---

```
 BEGIN{RS="\n/"} #set RS 
    {printf "%s",$0}  # print record
    /create/{printf "%s"," TABLESPACE TS"} #append if create is present in record
    {printf "%s",RS} # append seperator
```

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-specific due to multi-char RS. Also, always use `printf "%s", $0` instead of `printf $0` - imagine the difference when `$0` contains printf formatting characters like `%s`.